# On Click Change another elements source

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes, image

Working version of broken code here http://jsfiddle.net/Uey6W/8/

Having trouble figuring out how to change an attribute on another element form a click function

sniping

```
$('#black').click(function() {
$('#blackbox').slideToggle('slow', function() {});
$('#yellowbox').slideUp();
});
```

here on the click im hoping to not just hide the other element but also revert the other button

Basically how can i toggle another button to its closed state when another button switches to being open

```
$("#black").toggle(
    function () {
      var src = $(this).attr("src").replace("ready.png", "pressed.png");
      $(this).attr("src", src);
     },
    function () {
      var src = $(this).attr("src").replace("pressed.png", "ready.png");
      $(this).attr("src", src);
    }
);
$('#black').click(function() {
$('#blackbox').slideToggle('slow', function() {});
$('#yellowbox').slideUp();
});

$("#yellow").toggle(
    function () {
      var src = $(this).attr("src").replace("ready.png", "pressed.png");
      $(this).attr("src", src);
     },
    function () {
      var src = $(this).attr("src").replace("pressed.png", "ready.png");
      $(this).attr("src", src);
    }
);
$('#yellow').click(function() {
$('#yellowbox').slideToggle('slow', function() {});
$('#blackbox').slideUp();
});
```

Comment: can you show what you are trying to change

Comment: ok, im just having trouble phrasing this for whatever reason

Comment: So I've just strafe jQuery but how I understand thgis is: you're defining a function `toggle()´ to switch the image when pressed. But I don't see where you call that function in the onlick-handler of the other button? Perhaps that's your problem!?

Answer (score 1):

<strike>From what I can see in the [api reference](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/), toggle doesn't take two functions as parameters.</strike> And you're passing an empty function to slideToggle (just omit the empty function as a parameter if that's the intention). It looks like you're on the right train of thought with just a few errors.

Edit: Was looking at the wrong toggle. Correct documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/).

Answer (score 0):

Answer was right in my face the whole time inorder to revert the other buttons i just alter the click statement

```
$('#black').click(function() {
$('#blackbox').slideToggle('slow', function() {});
$('#yellowbox').slideUp();
    $('yellow').atr('src', ready.png)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pretty much achieve the exact same thing by doing :

```
var btn1 = "ready.png",
    btn2 = "pressed.png";

$("#black, #yellow").on('click', function() {
    $("#black, #yellow").not(this).prop('src', this.src);
    this.src = this.src==btn1 ? btn2 : btn1;
    $('#'+this.id+'box').slideToggle('slow').siblings('div').slideUp('slow');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Uey6W/12/)